# 2TB GPT Disk mistakenly shown as a larger 8TB GPT Disk with unallocated partitions - Why?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-11, usb-storage

I plugged in a 8TB GPT HDD in my pc via external usb adapter (see Footnote 1 for adapters). Then I safely removed and physically unplugged the adapter from the PC, turned off the PC. Next day I plugged the adapter in again with a 2TB HDD, and it's mistakenly shown as larger: with the correct 1863.01GB partition, and 2 fake unallocated space partitions:

[image]

Is the windows partitoning scheme wrongly intertwined across Disks now? The Disk name in the screenshow is (wrongly) the name of the 8TB disk (but I don't have any "184.98" and "5404.04" partitions) but the name of the 1863.01 partition is that of the 2TB disk, which works "correctly".

What exactly is breaking here, and how can I fix this, and how could I prevent this? (while still being able to use usb with my old HDDs - "ditch sata & usb, get a new pc with m.2s" is not the range of answers I'm looking for )

At the risk of murking this question up, I've also had trouble sometimes when connecting these/similar drives via internal SATA (after they had "malfunctioned" this way via usb adapters) and windows still showed them as RAW / unallocated. Then plugged them back into a usb adapter, and they worked (And files were there etc).

So what I at least want to understand is why is Windows getting confused?

PS: This happened in windows 7, 10, and 11...

---

Footnote 1: I have and use at least 4 different usb adapters or docks from 4 different brands, all claim to support GPT / 8TB drives etc.

- This sort of hdd dock actually gave me a scarier problem: I had hdds A B C D. I then swapped to something like E B D C -- and now D was showing as C with half of D's content and C was showing as being part of D. Never using one of these again with more than 1 disks inside 
  [image]
- This sort of usb hdd adapter, which is what I used in the issue I described in the question. In this case I did use the same adapter both times, and possibly in the same usb port.
  [image]
- [usb hdd caddy](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=USB%20drive%20caddy&iax=images&ia=images) -- never used caddies

Comment: Are you using the same USB enclosure for both disks? Try : regedit to key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR`, export it for backup, then delete all its subkeys and reboot. Does it show the right size now?

Comment: @harrymc Could the problem be the result of a disk signature collision?

Comment: @Spectraljump I've never encountered that problem when using a USB drive dock - what sort of adapter are you using? If it's a USB drive caddy and you change drives over a lot, maybe a dock would be more convenient for you. (N.B. you still can't instantly hot-swap drives with them.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Yes, it might be a possible explanation. My answer would perhaps also solve such a problem (temporarily).

Comment: @AndrewMorton I appended more info about what usb adapters I used in the question. There shouldn't be a disk signature collision, the two HDDs are different brands and 5+ years apart in manufacture. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @harrymc Yes I did (updated question). Interesting regedit keys. I will try it as soon as my backup finishes... It could be a solution to delete these keys every time before or after using an external hdd adapter or dock. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Maybe external closure remembers the disks, have you tried to completely power it off before drive change? Or update enclosure firmware (if there is new one)?

Comment: @pbies I am not 100% sure; but as a principle I (at least briefly) power off the adapter/dock so the hdd is powered off when I pull it out of the adapter/dock. But I mean, these usb thingies, they are built to work with more than 1 hdd ever so why are they so broken lol

Comment: @Spectraljump *Without actually making any changes*, does a tool such as [AOMEI Partition Assistant](https://www.diskpart.com/download.html) show the same partitions as the Disk Manager in Windows?

Comment: @Spectraljump: Let me know if the registry key works for you, but this is still not normal. This problem really shouldn't be happening.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, other partitioning software such as aomei or minitool show the same as Windows Disk Management, for all disks in the system. The same wrong device name of the 8tb hdd, and the same working 2tb partition inside. This is on a fresh install of windows 11. Last time I had this sort of problem was in windows 10.

Comment: @Spectraljump Can you boot the computer from a [USB Linux](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started) stick and use the tools therein to check the partition table(s) on the drive(s)? That way, we can check if the problem is on the drives (however it happened), or something in the OS.

Comment: I couldn't safely remove this 2tb hdd, so I restarted the pc. After the restart, (with the hdd still connected) it was no longer seen in windows despite spinning and in the same usb port. I unplugged from usb port 1 and plugged it in usb port 2. Still no device recognized by windows. I unplugged the usb adapter, unplugged it from power, then re-plugged it to usb port 1. Then it was recognized and no longer shows wrong name or unallocated partitions. Data is correct/accessible.

Comment: The only thing I can compare now, is I made a registry backup of the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR` while the problem was happening. And compared it diff style in vscode with the current registry after restart. There's 0 diffs. Then I suspect the problem is that these (different brand, different form factor) hdd usb adapters and usb docks, have hardware id cahcing issues, so basically, to be safe, don't use multiple hdds with the same adapter (which yeah, is dumb). Also don't do any partition recovery on a hdd while it's attached via one of these adapters/docks.

Comment: I will continue to go through my hdds and will come back here with any updates / follow you guys' suggestions.